# vue.js - view index.html without a server

Tags: vue.js

I'm building an app with vue.js and this app needs to run later on a terminal without internet connection and without a running server. I want that my client just have to start the index.html file. Is this possible and what setup do i need?

When i start the index.html my only error message in console i get is:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///xxx/dist/ec0098eb6371c2f4342a.worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.

my register-service-worker.js looks like this to allow localhost

```
if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
  ('https:' === location.protocol || location.host.match(/(localhost|127.0.0.1)/)) &&
  navigator.serviceWorker
) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
}
```

i try now for days to find a solution. I already build half of my app and now i see that
it can't run locally. I hope someone knows a trick.
Thanks from Germany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service worker **needs** https or localhost to work. It will not work in file:// etc. (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)

For a one click start you could start such a server from a batch file, but you would have to assume your client has Node or python installed, then `npx http-server` or the like would work.

Lastly, if your App is completely offline and without a server, you might not need a service worker in the first place.

Comment: Thank you @Flink !
If i remove the service worker, my problem would be solved?

Comment: Without the worker you should be able to look at the site with a click on the index, yes